# MS Access query to insert off of last number

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am attempting to approach MS Access through VBA. One of the calls I'd like to do is an insert off of the last supplied number. This would need to select the last number that was entered and iterate from it by one. I can simply place this in a for-loop to create 30 of them, however, I am just trying to get the SQL syntax correct at this point. It seems that the select insert is having the an issue. The error I am receiving is "Query input must contain at least one table or query".

```
Dim StrSSQL As String

StrSQL = "INSERT INTO MyQueryTable (MYNUMBER) VALUES((Select top 1 MYNUMBER + 1 from MyQueryTable order by MYNUMBER desc));"

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL StrSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

However, doing an simple insert as `"INSERT INTO MyQueryTable (MYNUMBER) VALUES(999)"` works fine.

Comment: FYI AutoIncrement columns are designed for this and offer the advantage of not causing massive problems with concurrency.

Comment: (`NUMBER` is a reserved word so escape it as `[NUMBER]`.)

Comment: Correct, however this number is not in need of that as It can change on any manual insert. (Not a unique ID) Using this macro I have set in place should generate lets say 50 inserts on top of the last used number. Unless perhaps there is an efficient way to use auto increment on not unique numbers?

Comment: @AlexK. I have placed "NUMBER" there for an example. I'll change it.

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: @AlexK. I have added this to the question. I've also tried the last() functionality and had issues with the select on the insert portion to get the last number.

Comment: Remove `VALUES()` so `"INSERT INTO MyQueryTable (MYNUMBER) Select top 1 MYNUMBER + 1 AS N from MyQueryTable order by MYNUMBER desc;"`

Comment: why not: `INERT INTO [MyQueryTable] (MYNUMBER) VALUES ((SELECT MAX(MYNUMBER) + 1 FROM [MyQueryTable]))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO MyQueryTable (MyNumber)
SELECT MAX(MyNumber)+1
FROM MyQueryTable
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243852(v=office.12).aspx

Edit:  Just noticed @Alex K. wrote similar in the comments - sorry, didn't see it.

Comment: Very nice answer. This has worked for me. Also, as for my original post, removing "Values" and "parenthesis" worked as well.